# python: is there a way to sort tuples of multiple values inside a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have this list of tuples:

```
[(('milk',), 5),
 (('milk', 'eggs'), 3),
 (('yogurt', 'milk'), 3),
 (('eggs',), 3),
 (('yogurt',), 3),
 (('milk', 'eggs', 'yogurt'), 2),
 (('milk', 'bread'), 2),
 (('milk', 'cheese'), 2),
 (('yogurt', 'eggs'), 2),
 (('bread',), 2),
 (('cheese',), 2)]
```

I need to sort them by decreasing 2nd value then by decreasing number of first-value items, then by alphabetical order. The first and 2nd requirements, i have done already. As you can see their respective 2nd values are decreasing, and then by decreasing 1st-value items. My only problem are the list of items inside the first-value tuples. I can't arrange them alphabetically.

My expected output should be:

```
[(('milk',), 5),
 (('eggs', 'milk'), 3),
 (('milk', 'yogurt'), 3),
 (('eggs',), 3),
 (('yogurt',), 3),
 (('eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'), 2),
 (('bread', 'milk'), 2),
 (('cheese', 'milk'), 2),
 (('eggs', 'yogurt'), 2),
 (('bread',), 2),
 (('cheese',), 2)]
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable so you will need to create new ones:

```
lst = [(('milk',), 5),
       (('milk', 'eggs'), 3),
       (('yogurt', 'milk'), 3),
       (('eggs',), 3),
       (('yogurt',), 3),
       (('milk', 'eggs', 'yogurt'), 2),
       (('milk', 'bread'), 2),
       (('milk', 'cheese'), 2),
       (('yogurt', 'eggs'), 2),
       (('bread',), 2),
       (('cheese',), 2)]

out = [(tuple(sorted(items)), number) for items, number in lst]

print(out)
```

gives:

```
[(('milk',), 5), (('eggs', 'milk'), 3), (('milk', 'yogurt'), 3), (('eggs',), 3), (('yogurt',), 3), (('eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'), 2), (('bread', 'milk'), 2), (('cheese', 'milk'), 2), (('eggs', 'yogurt'), 2), (('bread',), 2), (('cheese',), 2)]
```

This is after doing whatever you have already done to obtain the sorted list shown in the question (1st and 2nd requirements).

Comment: Thank you! this worked wonderfully. May I kindly ask for an explanation as to how this arranged the values inside the tuple?

Comment: The `sorted` function will create a list of sorted values, and then calling `tuple` on the output of that function will generate a **new** tuple containing those values in that sorted order. Hence my point that it does not change the ordering in the existing tuple.

Comment: Here, the variable `items` (on each iteration inside the list comprehension) contains the relevant original tuple - this is after unpacking the two elements of each of the outer tuples into the variables `items` and `number`.

Comment: Ah I see. So for immutable variables, there is really no way to manipulate it in anyway? I really have to 'take them out' and make new ones? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I am just making new ones. I suppose at a stretch I could have reused the existing outer list (because lists are mutable), by doing `lst[:] = ...` instead of `out = ...`, but unless you have other references to that list elsewhere, there is probably not much gain in doing that.

Comment: Actually this list is the output already so yeah, this solution is enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [(('milk',), 5),
 (('milk', 'eggs'), 3),
 (('yogurt', 'milk'), 3),
 (('eggs',), 3),
 (('yogurt',), 3),
 (('milk', 'eggs', 'yogurt'), 2),
 (('milk', 'bread'), 2),
 (('milk', 'cheese'), 2),
 (('yogurt', 'eggs'), 2),
 (('bread',), 2),
 (('cheese',), 2)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(sorted(((tuple(sorted(a)), b) for a, b in lst), key=lambda k: (-k[1], -len(k[0]), k[0])))
```

Prints:

```
[(('milk',), 5),
 (('eggs', 'milk'), 3),
 (('milk', 'yogurt'), 3),
 (('eggs',), 3),
 (('yogurt',), 3),
 (('eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'), 2),
 (('bread', 'milk'), 2),
 (('cheese', 'milk'), 2),
 (('eggs', 'yogurt'), 2),
 (('bread',), 2),
 (('cheese',), 2)]
```

---

Note: I assume your initial list is unsorted.